# WxPython: не работает RESIZE_BORDER

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython, wxwidgets, ubuntu-unity

Ситуация в следующем.
Есть две Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, одна дома (поставлена вместо Debian), вторая на работе (поставлена "с нуля").
Есть python-скрипт использующий wxPython: создаётся главное окно `(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)`, затем дочернее `(wx.RESIZE_BORDER)`.

Дома: всё работает как и положено -- дочернее окно без оформления, но ресайзится.
На работе: дочернее окно без заголовка не ресайзится (через пункт меню по Alt+ПКМ -- таки ресайзится), с заголовком `(wx.CAPTION)` -- ресайзится.  ￼

ЧЯДНТ? Дело в либах или в настройках системы?

P.S.: В xfce и gnome-shell у окна всегда есть заголовок (не убирается).

Comment: А среда рабочего стола на обоих машинах одинаковая? Что вы имеете ввиду под "поставлена вместо дебиана" ?

Comment: Да, на обеих родная Unity. Стоял Debian (xfce), хомяк на отдельном разделе, на раздел с debian была поставлена ubuntu, подцеплен хомяк. Собственно, думаю, это не важно.

Comment: Версии wxpython одинаковые?

Comment: Да, обе версии 2.8.12.1

Comment: Возможно, дело все-таки в разных настройках среды рабочего стола на ваших убунтах, больше предположений нет.

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

Возможно, дело все-таки в разных настройках среды рабочего стола на ваших убунтах, больше предположений нет.

добавка от меня: следует попробовать запустить программу от имени вновь созданного пользователя.